# Software to spellcheck an HTML / ASP.NET source

Tags: asp.net, text-editor

English is not my native language.
I need a software to spellcheck and correct the HTML source code.

The spellchecking itself is not a problem: I can e.g. publish the asp, then open the web server HTML response in Microsoft word.

However, I'd like to fix the document, too.

With Word 2007 as a spellchecker, the process is tricky and error-prone. I need to correct in word, then copy-paste to asp.net, then repair the HTML tags (tags like <i> and <a href=…> may be inside the sentence) -  refresh the browser - save - click OK button on the "sharing violation" error box - close word - save - reopen word - recheck.

Is there a text editor for Windows, that can check the document, while being aware of the HTML / ASP.NET markup, ignoring all that &nbsp;, <div …>, and <asp:Content …> (I'm not even mentioning JavaScript source code), not trying to correct them, but still check the spelling and punctuation of the text?

Or maybe there's an add-on for Visual Studio (I have 3 both 2005, 2008 and 2010 installed) that does what I need?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than copy the HTML, one tactic I've used in the past is to copy the content of the browser window, i.e. what's displayed, not the markup. You still have the "problem" of mapping that back to what's in Visual Studio, but it's relatively painless if you've got *most* of the spelling correct already!

There is also a [Spell Checker add-on](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/7c8341f1-ebac-40c8-92c2-476db8d523ce) for Visual Studio 2010. I can't comment as to how good it is, having not used it, but the rating is currently 4.5/5, which is a pretty good indicator!

Comment: I'm not spellchecking the HTML source, instead I open the HTML files in Word as HTML documents. My English is not _that_ bad, so yes, most of the spelling is OK.

However, I'll wait a bit, hoping someone will point me to the software I'm looking for: your approach still require me to copy from web browser to word, then copy to visual studio, then repair HTML.

Comment: Don't round-trip the whole file, just copy & paste out the content of the page. Word will highlight anything that needs correcting with its wavy lines and you can adjust those spellings directly in visual studio. Or, look at the Spell Checker add-on I mentioned =)

Answer (score 0):

HTML Spell Checker is a good one.download and install it in here:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/09cdc0c3-c50b-4bfd-a567-b7125c244b10?SRC=VSIDE